# ReactJS app with nodejs/express for backend - can't get api to backend working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to implement a React application which needs access to a database.  From what I have seen, this can be done with a nodejs/express as a backend.  In addition, I am under the impression that by adding a proxy entry to my react package.json file that I can redirect the "/api" requests of the fetch calls to the backend server.  However, I don't think it is working.  In the browser console, is showing a 404 error on the localhost:3000 (which is the NPM react server).  My backend is running on port 5000.

I can access the "http://localhost:5000/api" of the backend server and it returns JSON as designed.

Here is my react package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ubwo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy":"http://localhost:5000/api",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "browserslist": "4.6.2",
    "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30000974"
  }
}
```

This is my "test" React code.  I am not too familiar with fetch, so perhaps the code needs some changes?:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.callApi()
        .then(res => this.setState({ response: res.express}))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

callApi = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/cust/all',{
        headers:{
            "accepts":"application/json"
        }
    });
    const customers = await response.json();
    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(customers.message);

    return customers;
}
```

Comment: Can you try just with `"proxy":"http://localhost:5000"`? I'm not quite sure but with the current setup proxy probably will redirect to something like this `/api/api/cust/all` for your endpoints.

Comment: Does it work if you try `npm run build` and work from there? AFAIK react-scripts uses webpack-dev-server so your proxy would be best set up through `devServer.proxy` in your webpack config (which is hidden away until you eject iirc)

As an easy fix you can just remove the proxy and make your fetch request to `fetch('localhost:5000/api/cust/all')` - although once you host this somewhere the base url will change from localhost.

Comment: Proxy works without any problem and any custom config with CRA and hence "react-scripts" on development. No need to be ejected or do any custom setup. If OP tries to make a request directly probably they get a CORS problem.

Comment: devserkan:  If I cannot use the direct URL as some of the earlier responses have indicated, are you aware of a solution?  I am not trying to reinvent the wheel.  I was using the proxy because I had read that solution on a few different blogs about the topic.  If there is a better way, for development as well as production, I am open to it.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `/api/foo` in your fetch call, it will execute the request against the url you are currently on. So your API request is expanding to

`http://localhost:3000/api/foo`

As you stated your API server is running on `http://localhost:5000`. So what you need to do here is provide the entire path to your `fetch` request.

```
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/foo`)
```

As you might guess, this will cause problems when you go to production, so a typical pattern is to use an environment variable that can be configured:

```
fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/foo`)
```

See [create-react-app environment variable docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should remove the `/api` at the end of your proxy value in your package.json file

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't have the /api at the end originally, but I added it in the process of experimenting with different configurations to try and get it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you could check if you have a json parser in use on your back end in your main server file like:

```
express.urlencoded([options])
```

or

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser);
bodyParser.json([options])
```